# Toggle navigation elements in Umbraco

Tags: javascript, umbraco7

I have an Umbraco tree navigation. I want to toggle the children (show/hide) when clicking on a parent. Initially only the root element is shown. Right know I have all elements displayed. My code looks like this:

```
<div>
        @foreach (var childPage in sectionPage.Children.Where("Visible"))
        {
             @Umbraco.Field("umbracoNaviHide")
                 <p>

                 <a href="@childPage.Url">@childPage.Name</a>
                            @* if the current page has any children, where the property umbracoNaviHide is not True *@
                            @if (childPage.Children.Where("Visible").Any())
                            {                    
                                @* Call our helper to display the children *@
                                @childPages(childPage.Children)
                            }
                 </p>
             <!--}-->
        }
    </div>

 @helper childPages(dynamic pages) 
    { @* Ensure that we have a collection of pages @ if (pages.Any()) { @ Get the first page in pages and get the level *@ var naviLevel = pages.First().Level;
        @* Add in level for a CSS hook *@
        <div class="level-@(naviLevel)">
            @foreach (var page in pages.Where("Visible"))
            {
                <p>
                    <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
                    @* if the current page has any children, where the property umbracoNaviHide is not True *@
                    @if (page.Children.Where("Visible").Any())
                    {                        
                        @* Call our helper to display the children *@
                        @childPages(page.Children)
                    }
                </p>
            }
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? With CSS? With Javascript? Have you tried to create a static structure instead and see if it works?

Comment: Code above works. I need only to make it toggle on parent elements. Right now iam trying to use toc bootsrap plugin, but have some problems...

Comment: I think you should try to get help to find your problems with bootstrap instead looking for someone to do the job for you.